# How do you access the frame number inside AVAsynchronousCIImageFilteringRequest?

Tags: avfoundation, cifilter, avvideocomposition

When using a `CIFilter` with an `AVVideoComposition`, how can I access the current frame number in the `AVAsynchronousCIImageFilteringRequest` callback?

The best I was able to do is estimate the frame number from the time:

```
^(AVAsynchronousCIImageFilteringRequest * _Nonnull request) {
    double seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(request.compositionTime);
    double fps = [[_avAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] firstObject].nominalFrameRate;
    int frame = round(seconds * fps);

    // (Calculate filter parameters based on frame number)
}
```

But this isn't accurate enough for me.  Is there a way to access the frame number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to set the `frameDuration` on the `AVMutableVideoComposition` to match that of the underlying `AVAssetTrack`.  if you do this, then the values of `compositionTime` will be even multiples of `minFrameDuration` and there won't be any rounding issues.

```
AVMutableVideoComposition *vidComp =
    [AVMutableVideoComposition videoCompositionWithAsset:self.avAsset
                            applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:
        ^(AVAsynchronousCIImageFilteringRequest * _Nonnull request) {
            CMTime frame = self.avAssetTrack.minFrameDuration;
            int frameNum = (request.compositionTime.value * frame.timescale) /
                           (request.compositionTime.timescale * frame.value);

            // (Calculate filter parameters based on frame number)
        }];

vidComp.frameDuration = self.avAssetTrack.minFrameDuration;
```

In my case of a ~60 fps MP4 movie, `avAssetTrack.minFrameDuration = (1001/60000)`, but `vidComp.frameDuration = (1501/90000)` before I update it.  This resulted in slow drift of 'compositionTime' in the callback, which resulted in occasional repeated frames.

Comment: I'm curious how you're setting vidComp.frameDuration since it's read only.

Comment: It's not read-only in an `AVMutableVideoComposition` (as opposed to an `AVVideoComposition`).

Answer (score 0):

How about (a hacky)

```
__block int frameNum = 0;

AVMutableVideoComposition *vidComp = 
    [AVMutableVideoComposition videoCompositionWithAsset:self.avAsset
        applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:^(AVAsynchronousCIImageFilteringRequest * request) {

        // (Calculate filter parameters based on frame number)

        frameNum++;
    }];
```

?

There are two assumptions here:

1. your handler is called in the same order as the frames
2. your handler is not called by more than one thread at a time

I don't know if these are safe assumptions or not.

p.s. frame rates are quite often variable, so min, max and frame duration can be misleading.

**UPDATE** the `AVComposition` from the question is intended for seekable playback in an `AVPlayer` which violates assumption 1.

Comment: The video is being played through an AVPlayerView, so the user can seek anywhere they want in the video, or play FF or reverse, and I need to know the frame number even in these cases.

Comment: As far as I can tell, if you set `vidComp.frameDuration`, then `compositionTime` in the callback will always be an exact multiple of that even if the frame rate of the videos being composed are variable.

Comment: Oh. I should add that my answer will definitely not work for arbitrary playback. That's a cool trick with `frameDuration`/`compositionTime`. Can you accept your answer yet?